# Routing through-hole USB port

Tags: pcb, usb, through-hole

The difference in lengths of the differential pairs are tremendous, which is quite evident in the screenshot. I just don't see how I am supposed to length-match this. Tips will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Length match does not usually (if ever) mean a perfect match.

Comment: Whats the hole diameter and the width of your traces?

Comment: There is always some tolerance so the lengths never have to match **exactly**. What your tolerance is depends on the frequencies of the signals, so USB speed. You mention nothing about this. Also, grab a PCB with a USB connector from the junk-box. Observe what they have done there. Profit.

Comment: If the length mismatch is << risetime, then simply execute the layout to match the capacitances. That includes any underlying planes (VDD or GND) and the parallel-plate capacitances.

Comment: You can meander the trace in other places to even out the length, but those look like some pretty thick traces. USB should be routed with a 90-ohm differential. Something like a 12-mil width with a 4-mil spacing should give you the 90-ohm differential, and you may be able to route the + signal between the pads. Or switch to surface mount, the USB ports aren't difficult to solder by hand.

Comment: @AntoineLev the width is 15mil and the diameter is 30mil.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks for the tip. The gap between the two through-holes are 9mil. I think it will be difficult to route a trace through this. I originally had surface mounted port, but it was not very secure, so I switched to through hole part. I would prefer the 5 pins remained surface mount, but I couldn't find any!

Comment: [Here is a through hole one](https://www.amphenolcanada.com/ProductSearch/drawings/AC/UE27ACX4X0X.pdf) that has the contacts in-line. [Here is one that is SMD with through-hole bracing](http://portal.fciconnect.com/Comergent//fci/drawing/87583.pdf) that I like to use on my projects. Unless this is USB-B?

Comment: You don't mention the USB speed you want to use. With Full Speed there is no problem at all, at High Speed length should be matched to about 2 cm difference max (but impedance is more important). Nothing to worry about here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned without the applicable USB speed specification ever being stated and because the only answer a link to a product recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

I found this: http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/usb_a.pdf

You are facing problem with routing because your component doesn't have all pins in-line. The part mentioned above has pins in same line and should get you through.